# Elasticsearch query range precision problem for small values

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I've a database with a few thousand values-timestamp pairs I want to query and filter. Typical timestamps are:

```
2019-06-15T15:09:14.0191875+02:00
2019-06-15T15:09:14.0195000+02:00
2019-06-15T15:09:14.0194375+02:00
2019-06-15T15:09:14.0198750+02:00
2019-06-15T15:09:14.0190000+02:00
2019-06-15T15:09:14.0190625+02:00
2019-06-15T15:09:14.0191875+02:00
```

As you can see, they only vary in the range of microseconds. When I use the following query, I receive all those values.

```
{
 "size": 500,
 "sort": [
  {
   "timestamp": {
   "order": "desc"
  }}],
 "query": {
   "range": {
     "timestamp": {
      "time_zone": "+02:00",
      "gt": "2019-06-15T15:09:14.01",
      "lt": "2019-06-15T15:09:14.02"
     }
    }
   }
 }
```

When I change gt and lt to e.g. "2019-06-15T15:09:14.0**191**" and "2019-06-15T15:09:14.0**196**", the result is empty. The same happens for the value query.

```
65.59359741210938
0.149688720703125
0.0748443603515625
0.014968873001635075
0.2395019680261612
```

If I use the this query

```
{
  "size": 1000,
  "sort": [
    {
      "value": {
      "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "range" : {
      "value": {
        "gte": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting results including the aforementioned values. When I change  **gte** to **0.02** and add  **"lte": 0.09** the result is empty. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Your `timestamp` is probably of type `date` which stores dates in millisecond resolution. So what you need is [`date_nanos`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date_nanos.html#date_nanos).

Drop the index, change the mapping to

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date_nanos"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then reindex and you're good to go.

*Note that this is only supported in 7.0 and onwards. [Here's the story of the journey from millis to nanos.](https://www.elastic.co/blog/journey-support-nanosecond-timestamps-elasticsearch)*

Comment: I am still trying. I will catch you up when I figured it out!

Comment: Hey, its me again. I was able to identify some of my problems. First, the version which is used in this specific example is 5.6.14, so no chance in solving the date issue with your answer. Second, the empty results for the value field is caused by a wrong mapping, which is set to "long" and should be "double" or "float".

Comment: Yea too bad it's only 5.6. Good that you figured it out. The only downside to a purely numeric field (and not `date` with a format) is that while you will be able to do simple `range` queries on it, they won't be able to be relative (like `now-1y`). Also, histogram aggregations are out of the picture (except for scripting), plus time zones may not be the easiest to implement. But it looks like you're only doing range queries here so you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Joe for clearing out some of my questions. Is this also the problem why I cant search for exact timestamps (with the given ns accuracy)? Most of the time my query includes ranges or an exact timestamp and every time I got results which have other timestamps included or are out of the range itself.